# Pandas convert types and set invalid values as na

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to convert pandas series values to a specific type and set those elements n/a that cannot be converted?

I found `Series.astype(dtype, copy=True, raise_on_error=True)` with and set `raise_on_error=True` to avoid exceptions, but this won't set invalid items to na...

**Update**

More precisely, I want to specify the type a column should be converted to. For a series containing values `[123, 'abc', '2010-01-01', 1.3]` and a type conversion to `float`, I'd expect `[123.0, nan, nan, 1.3]` as result, if `datetime` is chosen, only the `series[2]` would contain a valid datetime value. `convert_objects` doesn't allow this kind of flexibility, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have better luck with [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['1', '2', 'a'])

In [12]: s.astype(int, raise_on_error=False)  # just returns s
Out[12]:
0    1
1    2
2    a
dtype: object

In [13]: s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[13]:
0     1
1     2
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Update: In more recent pandas the `convert_objects` method has been deprecated.
In favor of [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
In [21]: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
Out[21]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

This isn't quite as powerful/magical as `convert_objects` (which also worked on DataFrames) but works well and is more explicit in this case.
*Read the [object conversion section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#object-conversion), where other `to_*` functions are mentioned.*

Comment: I just saw the function signature: `convert_objects(self, convert_dates=True, convert_numeric=False, convert_timedeltas=True, copy=True)`. It's not really possible to force it to convert to a specific type, isn't it?

Comment: floats, dates, deltas... almost always you want these (Note: ints can't have NaN).

Comment: In some cases, the file would contain ints that I need to interpret as string. This heuristic wouldn't work...

Comment: @orange you said: "set invalid items to na" this does that. If you want to be more picky then you could use some mask/criteria to manually set to NaN (but I don't see how you would expect astype to do that :s)

Comment: @AndyHayden I've updated my question to refine my requirements. Thanks for your help so far (`convert_objects` was new to me and may be useful in future).

Comment: @orange for dates you should use `pd.to_datetime` (with coerce=True). Please upvote the answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
s.astype(int, raise_on_error=False)
s = s.apply(lambda x: x if type(x)==int else np.nan)
s = s.dropna()
```

Comment: This doesn't address several issues. astype will raise an error if the values aren't numeric. So if there's a problem in the first line, the second and third lines won't execute. And if there isn't a problem in the first line, then the second and third lines are irrelevant.